# xlEdgeRight only applies border to last cell in the Range

Tags: excel, vba

So, I am trying to apply a border on the right side of a range in vba, but the code will only apply the border on the last cell in the range, i.e., D5.

```
With Range("A5: D5").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
     .LineStyle = xlContinuous
     .Weight = xlMedium
     .Color = vbYellow
End With
```

Also, prior to adding the right-side border, I'm adding a border to all sides on a larger range, including the one above, by executing the following:

```
With Range("A5: J7").Borders
     .LineStyle = xlContinuous
     .Weight = xlMedium
End With
```

Is it an overwriting issue?

Comment: It does that. The other cells in the range have an `xlInsideVertical` border.  The `xlEdgeRight` applies to the range, not the cells in the range... noting that a range can be a single cell as well.  [XlBordersIndex enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.XlBordersIndex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
For Each ecell In Range("A5: D5")
     ecell.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
     ecell.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
     ecell.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = vbYellow
Next ecell
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than look at each cell, just set the `xlInsideVertical` border.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:D5")
    
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 10 To 11
    '10 = xlEdgeRight & 11 = xlInsideVertical
        With rng.Borders(x)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .Color = vbYellow
        End With
    Next x

End Sub
```